# Subscription plugin in wordpress to manage Daily/Monthly/Weekly/Yearly subscriptions

Tags: wordpress, plugins, subscription

I am developing a wordpress website for Milk delivery where customer can subscribe milk on a daily/weekly/monthly basis and make payment accordingly. Can you please suggest the best plugin to handle this? Are there free plugins in the market?

Answer (score 0):

You can use free version of S2M plugin. 
There are few more available like paidmembership,ultimatemember plugins and woocommerce subscription etc These are the best plugins. There are free versions also available with limited features.

Comment: Can you please share the link of free versions?